Why does my checkbox break if the onChange handler is a parent function that has a useState hook?
I have the following CodeSandbox:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(arr);
  }, [arr]);

  function outerFunction(index) {
    console.log(index);
    setArr([index]); // comment this out and everything else works
  }

  const Row = ({ index }) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    return (
      <>
        <input
          name="mychecky"
          type="checkbox"
          //  checked={checked}
          onChange={() => outerFunction(index)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="mychecky">My checkbox</label>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row index={3} />
    </div>
  );
}

The onChange handler for the checkbox is a parent function that works fine UNTIL you add the useState hook (e.g. setArr(3)). How can I make the checkbox function normally?

This happens because you define the Row component inside of the App component. So in each rerender of the App you create a new Row component and the <Row index={3} /> needs to be unmounted and a new one mounted.
If you move the definition outside of App it will work fine. (do not forget to pass the function you want through the props)
export default function App() {
  ...

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row index={3} outerFunction={outerFunction} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Row = ({ index, outerFunction }) => {
  ...
}

Read https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#nesting-and-organizing-components for more info why nesting the definitions of components is bad
